# Where to use ":eq" and ".eq()" in jquery

Tags: jquery

IF `:eq()` and `.eq()` is same functionality, why two methods.
Is any purpose?

OR

Where to Use `:eq()`?

Where to Use `.eq()`?

Comment: A little googling goes a long way http://forum.jquery.com/topic/eq-vs-eq for more results https://www.google.ca/search?q=jquery+%3Aeq+vs+.eq&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=kE00U7PiBMfB8geG9IDQCQ

Comment: @Huangism: I have seen that topic, but I didn't get clear picture, that's why I posted this Question

Comment: y'all are missing the OP's actual question. He's not asking what the difference is. He's already asking under the assumption that both do the same thing. His question is WHY there are both if they do the same thing

Comment: .. and to answer that question, just like there are synonyms in regular language, there's lots of ways to do the same thing in jQuery or js or programming language in general. sometimes it just boils down to personal preference, what feels more clear and natural to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference (other than performance) is usage.

One is a selector and one is a method.

For example, here are two examples that do basically the same thing.

`$('#test li:eq(1) span');` Is using `:eq()` as part of a selector

`$('#test li').eq(1).find("span");` is using `.eq()` as a method and running a find on the returned jquery object.

Aside from performance hits, the preference is up to the developer.  In my opinion, the first one is more readable, but in a situation where there is no need to find `span`, I would go with the second one.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-eq

They both do the same thing. Except one is slower. (`:eq`)

So use `.eq()` if you're worried about performance.

As [Smeegs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693175/where-to-use-eq-and-eq-in-jquery/22693231?noredirect=1#comment34574980_22693231) has said in the comments, `:eq` is part of a selector. This means more can be added after it. eg

```
$('#test li:eq(1) span');
```

Comment: Also, `:eq` is part of a selector, which means more can be added after it. like `$('#test li:eq(1) span');`

Comment: @Smeegs: Can you give more? That's the answer I am looking

Comment: @Smeegs you can still using `.eq()` filter the result and should be faster. Indeed, fastest solution should be: `$('#test').find('li').eq(1).find('span')`

Comment: @A.Wolff Of course you can, but we're talking about the differences between `.eq()` and `:eq`.  Saying that it returns a jquery object is a bit off topic.